# What is the maximum amount of records can jparespositry saveAll can handle at a time?

Tags: database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-batch

in my spring-boot application I am running a schedule job which is taking the record from one table and saving it another as archive, I just ran into a problem so now the records I have selected to be save are almost around 400,000 plus and when the job is executing it just keeps on going. Can the ja handle this much data to be saved at once? Below are my configuration and the method.

```
#--Additional Settings for Batch Processing --#
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=5000
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data = true
rewriteBatchedStatements=true
cachePrepStmts=true
```

The agentAuditTrailArchiveList object has size of 400,000 plus.

```
private void archiveAgentAuditTrail(int archiveTimePeriod) {
    List<AgentAuditTrail> archivableAgentAuditTrails = agentAuditTrailRepository
        .fecthArchivableData(LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(archiveTimePeriod));
    List<AgentAuditTrailArchive> agentAuditTrailArchiveList = new ArrayList<>();

    archivableAgentAuditTrails
        .forEach(agentAuditTrail -> agentAuditTrailArchiveMapper(agentAuditTrailArchiveList, agentAuditTrail));
    System.out.println(" agentAuditTrailArchiveList = " + agentAuditTrailArchiveList.size());
    System.out.println("archivableAgentAuditTrails = " + archivableAgentAuditTrails.size());
    agentAuditTrailArchiveRepository.saveAll(agentAuditTrailArchiveList);

    agentAuditTrailRepository.deleteInBatch(archivableAgentAuditTrails);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are actually doing this as a Spring Batch job this is already handled. You just need to set the chunk size within the batch job step config so it will only process a set number of records at a time.  See the Batch step config example below.

You never want to try to do the entire job as one commit unless it is always going to be really small.   Doing it all in one commit leaves you open to a laudatory list of failure conditions and data integrity problems.

```
@Bean
public Step someStepInMyProcess(FlatFileItemReader<MyDataObject> reader,
        MyProcesssor processor, ItemWriter<MyDataObject> writer) {
    return stepBuilders.get("SomeStepName")
            .<MyDataObject, MyDataObject>chunk(50)
            .reader( reader )
            .processor( processor )
            .writer(writer)
            .transactionManager(transactionManager)
            .build();
}
```